# Error installing OpenSSL-Apple Cocoapod. Build fails

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to install OpenSSL-Apple Cocoapod as a dependency on a project but the build fails like so

```
[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
./build-libssl.sh --version="1.1.1l" --targets="ios-sim-cross-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64e macos64-x86_64 macos64-arm64 mac-catalyst-x86_64 mac-catalyst-arm64"
./create-openssl-framework.sh dynamic


Build options
  OpenSSL version: 1.1.1l
  Targets: ios-sim-cross-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64e macos64-x86_64 macos64-arm64 mac-catalyst-x86_64 mac-catalyst-arm64
  iOS SDK: 15.4 (min 12.0)
  macOS SDK: 12.3 (min 10.15)
  macOS SDK (Catalyst): 12.3 (min 10.15)
  watchOS SDK: 8.5 (min 4.0)
  tvOS SDK: 15.4 (min 12.0)
  Number of make threads: 8
  Configure options:  no-deprecated
  Build location: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple

Downloading openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for iPhoneSimulator 15.4 x86_64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/iPhoneSimulator15.4-x86_64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for iPhoneSimulator 15.4 arm64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/iPhoneSimulator15.4-arm64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for iPhoneOS 15.4 arm64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/iPhoneOS15.4-arm64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for iPhoneOS 15.4 arm64e...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/iPhoneOS15.4-arm64e.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for MacOSX 12.3 x86_64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/MacOSX12.3-x86_64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for MacOSX 12.3 arm64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/MacOSX12.3-arm64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for Catalyst 12.3 x86_64...
  Logfile: /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/Catalyst12.3-x86_64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Problem during make - Please check /private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/bin/Catalyst12.3-x86_64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9603k  100 9603k    0     0  3645k      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 3658k
```

whereas the file in question has this at the end

```
clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
clang: clang: error: clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:701: apps/s_cb.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Makefile:677: apps/apps.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:693: apps/opt.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:685: apps/bf_prefix.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:709: apps/s_socket.o] Error 1
clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:720: crypto/aes/aes_cbc.o] Error 1
clang: error: invalid version number in '-target x86_64-apple-ios13.0-macabi'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:669: apps/app_rand.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:728: crypto/aes/aes_cfb.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/mg/vh8gm88n7q9fz88_0zx52b2c0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try/OpenSSL-Apple/src/Catalyst-x86_64/openssl-1.1.1l'
make: *** [Makefile:174: all] Error 2
```

When I try to do command directly though

```
./build-libssl.sh --version="1.1.1l" --targets="ios-sim-cross-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64e macos64-x86_64 macos64-arm64 mac-catalyst-x86_64 mac-catalyst-arm64"
```

the process is successful...

```
Building openssl-1.1.1l for Catalyst 12.3 x86_64...
  Logfile: /Users/steinmacht/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/OpenSSL-Apple/1.1.1l.11-fb93d/bin/Catalyst12.3-x86_64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Building openssl-1.1.1l for Catalyst 12.3 arm64...
  Logfile: /Users/steinmacht/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/OpenSSL-Apple/1.1.1l.11-fb93d/bin/Catalyst12.3-arm64.sdk/build-openssl-1.1.1l.log
  Configure...
  Make (using 8 thread(s))...
Done.
```

Tried many different reinstalls,but the problem persists preventing me from initializing the project.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem; since I don't need Catalyst support (that's where the build fails), I removed that by doing the following:

- Open the Pod's folder (in your case `/Users/steinmacht/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/OpenSSL-Apple/1.1.1l.11-fb93d` - it's visible in the log)
- Copy the `OpenSSL-Apple.podspec` file and remove the architectures from `openssl_targets`. In my case it now reads

```
    openssl_targets   = "ios-sim-cross-x86_64 ios-sim-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64 ios64-cross-arm64e macos64-x86_64 macos64-arm64"
```

- Host that file somewhere, e.g. `https://www.example.com/podspecs/OpenSSL-Apple.podspec`
- Change your `Podfile` to use a private podspec file (as described at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)):

```
  pod 'OpenSSL-Apple', :podspec => 'https://www.project3851.com/podspecs/OpenSSL-Apple.podspec'
```

(it's possible it works with just a path reference, I haven't tested that)

You need a private podspec file since `pod install` will update it from the remote library, even if you modify it. It's entirely possible that there are better ways to do this, I'm only a very incidental Pod user.

Anyway, after this `pod install` worked again for me and the mobile app works as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use local version of openSSL

```
git clone https://github.com/passepartoutvpn/openssl-apple.git
```

Then edit run command in file `OpenSSL-Apple.podspec`

And in the PodFile set

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Apple', :path => '/Users/artem/XCode/openssl-apple'
```